# How to programmatically determine which Jenkins slave node has been used to run a build?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Let's says I have configured a Jenkins job which can run on a few Jenkins slave nodes (e.g. Node1, Node2, Node3, etc). When a build is started, Jenkins will select an available Jenkins slave to run the Build.

For a Build which has completed, or is currently running, how to programmatically determine which Jenkins slave node has been used to run the Build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Jenkins REST API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) to query an existing build assuming you know the build number:

`http://jenkins:8080/job/JOB_NAME/100/api/json?pretty=true`

The `builtOn` field shows the name of the slave which is running/ran the build.

To retrieve only a couple fields of the JSON build information, use the `tree` parameter:

`http://jenkins:8080/job/JOB_NAME/100/api/json?tree=id,timestamp,builtOn&pretty=true`

This will return something like:

```
{
  "id" : "2014-12-01_06-18-17",
  "timestamp" : 1417443497917,
  "builtOn" : "sdev05"
}
```

Most pages in the Jenkins UI have a *REST API* link at the bottom indicating they expose information that can be queried programmatically.